# How to define a boolean expression and evaluate it only when used?

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, lazy-evaluation

Let's go straight to an example:

```
public bool MeetsAllConditions()
{
    bool check1, check2, check3;

    // Some code to define result of check1
    if (something...)
    {
        if (something...)
        {
            check1 = true;
        }
    }

    // many more code to define check2 and check3
    ....

    if (check1 && check2 && check3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, the code to define each `check` is very **expensive**. Hence I would like to make it so that the code that defines result of each check is evaluated **only** **in** **the final** `if` statement. This way I can utilise lazy evaluation to save resource if **any** of the check **fails**.

How would I approach this **without defining a separate method** for each `check` in C#?

Comment: You could do something as simple as `if (!check1) return false;` after your check1 lines, and similar after each subsequent check. Then just `return true;` at the bottom.

Comment: However, "many more code" times three indicates your code would be more maintainable if you *did* make a separate method for each check.

Comment: I didn't want to make them separate methods because they were too specific to the main method I am writing. returning false after each statement..seemed to make my code dirty :( but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Maybe the main method you're writing should move into its own class, and the check methods could then be private to that class? Something to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends by what you mean by a "separate method". If you're willing to create delegates inline in your code, you could do something like this:

```
Func<bool> check1 = () =>
{
  if(something...)
  {
    if(something...)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
...

return check1() && check2() && check3();
```

Another option is simply to short-circuit and return early any time you notice something that should cause you to return false.

```
if(!something...)
{
  return false;
}
if(!something...)
{
  return false;
}
... // same pattern for check2 and check3
return true;
```

Comment: I guess OP wants to achieve without defining a method.  `How would I approach this without defining a separate method for each check in C#?`

Comment: @HariPrasad: Right, but what is meant by "separate method?" Does he just mean a named method? That's what my first sentence is pointing out.

Comment: Hey man thanks, I was wondering if there is some magical logic that could prevent defining a method and achieve this. I did not want to go for methods because I wanted to keep them inside my `MeetsAllChecks()` since they were very specific to only the method.

Comment: But actually `delegate` is interesting, I'm from java background and wasn't really aware of such thing...this would be something I was looking for!! Thanks!

Comment: In C# the `if` statement expression already short circuits so you don't need to code independent `if` statements with their own `return` for each condition (so your second option is redundant).

Comment: @slugster: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I understand the words, but I don't see exactly what aspect of that second example you see as redundant.

Comment: Your second code block.... the separate if/returns aren't necessary in C# (although they may be in other languages). Doing `if (check1 && check2 && check3) { }` should be sufficient - the compiler will set it up so that check2 and check3 won't get evaluated/called if check1 fails.

Comment: @slugster: It's true that the `&&` operator short-circuits, but if `check2` is a boolean that's already been calculated by the time you get to the `if` statement then the bulk of the work has already been done, and the only work that's short-circuited is checking the boolean value. My first code block changed `check1`, etc. into lazily-invoked functions to leverage the behavior you're talking about, but my second example is assuming that you don't want to create these anonymous methods, so it gets rid of the various check variables entirely, relying on logic flow to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `Lazy<T>` ?

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Use lazy initialization to defer the creation of a large or
>   resource-intensive object, or the execution of a resource-intensive
>   task, particularly when such creation or execution might not occur
>   during the lifetime of the program.

Since you have mentioned Expensive Process, why not encapsulate the expensive process in a Type ?